# How to find when a row does not contain specified string phrases?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I want to exclude all the rows in a column that contain two specific strings. This means when the dataframe column 'message receiver' has the BOTH emails johnsmith@yahoo & ian@yahoo.com, remove that row. If just one of these emails are included, I want to see that row.

My starting dataframe is:

```
data2 = {'key':  ['AAAA-27293', 'BBBBB-27296','CCCC-4444','DDDD-6666'],

    'project_id': [ '105', '107', '109', '101'],

    'create_date': [ '2019-01-02','2019-01-16','2019-01-25', '2019-01-19'],

    'summary': ['Automated-email','Automated-email','Automated-email', 'Automated-email'],

    'description': [ 'Output','Output', 'Output', 'Output'],

    'issue': ['task','job','task', 'job'],

    'message reciever': ['johnsmith@yahoo' ' ian@yahoo' ,'ian@yahoo'' ryan@yahoo', 'brian@yahoo' ' johnsmith@yahoo', 'jose@yahoo johnsmith@yahoo' ],

    'message sender': ['jim@gmail','johnharris@aol', 'john@aol', 'rick@ustoday'],

    'checker': ['None','None', 'None', 'None'],

    'resolution': ['rejected','completed','paused', 'rejected'],

    'source': ['ABC123','ABC432', 'CCC123', 'DDD11'],

    'staus': ['resolved', 'resolved','None', 'resolved']
    }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns= 
    ['key','project_id','create_date','summary','description','issue','message reciever','message 
    sender','checker','resolution','source','status'])
```

My desired output would be:

```
data3 = {'key':  ['BBBBB-27296','CCCC-4444','DDDD-6666'],

    'project_id': [  '107', '109', '101'],

    'create_date': [ '2019-01-16','2019-01-25', '2019-01-19'],

    'summary': ['Automated-email','Automated-email', 'Automated-email'],

    'description': [ 'Output', 'Output', 'Output'],

    'issue': ['job','task', 'job'],

    'message reciever': ['ian@yahoo'' ryan@yahoo', 'brian@yahoo' ' johnsmith@yahoo', 'jose@yahoo johnsmith@yahoo' ],

    'message sender': ['johnharris@aol', 'john@aol', 'rick@ustoday'],

    'checker': ['None', 'None', 'None'],

    'resolution': ['completed','paused', 'rejected'],

    'source': ['ABC432', 'CCC123', 'DDD11'],

    'staus': [ 'resolved','None', 'resolved']
    }
  df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3,columns= 
      ['key','project_id','create_date','summary','description','issue','message reciever','message 
       sender','checker','resolution','source','status'])
```

The code that I tried to get my desired output was:

```
df2[(~df2['message reciever'].str.contains('johnsmith@yahoo')) & (~df2['message reciever'].str.contains('iansmith@yahoo'))]
```

The above returns me with the rows that does not contain either johnsmith@yahoo.com or iansmith@yahoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply and operation on both of them and take negation of whole

```
df2[~((df2['message reciever'].str.contains('johnsmith@yahoo')) & (df2['message reciever'].str.contains('iansmith@yahoo')))]
```

Comment: thanks. this worked, did not realize the ~ should go after grouping the & statements together